# How to jailbreak iPad2 3G 4.3.5?

Tags: jailbreak, ipad, ios

I just bought a new (refurbished) iPad2 3G, and it came with 4.3.5.

It seems I can't jailbreak it because:

- There's no jailbreak for 4.3.5
- There's no untethered jailbreak yet for 5.1.1
- I can't change the firmware to any other version because the signing windows have closed and I don't have any SHSH blobs saved

Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you'll just have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I think you may have missed your window.
It seems that a 5.1.1 jailbreak is not too far away (if the jailbreak rumour mill is to be believed), so you might just have to wait it out for that.